# Curl HTTPS request gives "SSL peer was not expecting a handshake message it received."

Tags: php, curl, https

I have this simple cURL code that works fine on one machine (PHP 5.2.17), but fails on another (PHP 5.6.13). On the newer version, the cURL call throws an exception with

> SSL peer was not expecting a handshake message it received.

the code is as follows:

```
private function postRequest($url, $request) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,  FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO,          "certificate.der");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,            1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,      $request);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,      array('Content-Type: text/xml'));

    $r = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($r == false) {
        $r = curl_error($curl);
    }

    return $r;
}
```

Comment: Is the value of `$url` the same?

Comment: @Halcyon yes. I copied the self-containing test code from the one machine to the other and it worked fine.

Comment: Question: what is the use of CURLOPT_CAINFO if CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER set to false?

Comment: @swidmann nothing, but I am debugging and this is the exact code that I was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,  CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3);
```

Options are:

```
CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT

CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1

TLSv1.x

CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2

SSLv2

CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3

SSLv3

CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0

TLSv1.0 (Added in 7.34.0)

CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1

TLSv1.1 (Added in 7.34.0)

CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2

TLSv1.2 (Added in 7.34.0)
```

---

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html

Comment: That worked, even though `curl_easy_setopt` does not exist on my system. Trying to validate on the certificate works better also, gives me a better error message. Thanks!